# How to fix too much time taken by python requests during get and post?

Tags: python, django, python-requests, cakephp-3.0, php-socket

There is one website written in CakePhp and I am moving to Django.
Some pages are making get/post request to another website to collect some information.

CakePhp

```
$start = time();
$socket = new HttpSocket();
$api_ret = $socket->get($url,$data,$this->header);
$end = time();
CakeLog::write('Time', print_r($end-$start,true));
```

Django

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
api_ret = requests.get(url,data,headers=self.header)
end = datetime.now()
print((end-start).total_seconds())
```

Time taken by `requests` is too long compare to CakePhp.

Is there anything I am doing wrong or Is there any other library that I can use ?
Please Help.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  There's no processing here, so your bottleneck is almost certainly the network transfer.

Comment: CakePhp is currently in production (Apache server) and Django is at my localhost. I am testing both from same computer. Is this may be the reason?

Comment: Do you mean that CakePhp is making a request to itself? That would be much faster than a request which goes across a network.

Comment: No, They are making request to a external website.

Comment: But remember that, with Apache, there is a long-running PHP interpreter.  It doesn't have to load.  The Python interpreter has to start a process and load..